# Objective-c Object not returning or print string

Tags: objective-c, object

I'm new to objective c and im having some problems with objects.

I believe the syntax of the program is correct but it doesn't seem to return any values or even output (NSLog) from within the method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYZPerson : NSObject

- (NSString *)sayHello;

@end

@implementation XYZPerson

- (NSString *)sayHello {
    NSString *test = @"test";
    return test;

}

@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    XYZPerson *newPerson;
    NSString *getString = [newPerson sayHello];
    NSLog(@"the returned string is :%@", getString);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never create an XYZPerson object.

Comment: (And you should have told us what was actually logged.  Likely it was something like "the returned string is :<null>".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to create an instance of `XYZPerson` and assign it to `newPerson`

```
newPerson = [[XYZPerson alloc] init];
```

otherwise `newPerson` is `nil` and calling method on `nil` always return `nil`

Comment: +1 to you for coming to the same conclusion as me at the same time

Answer (score 2):

"`newPerson`" is null when you call it.

You need to do:

```
newPerson = [[XYZPerson alloc] init];
```

before calling a method on it.

Answer (score 0):

Add in:

```
newPerson = [[XYZPerson alloc] init];
```

Right underneath:

```
XYZPerson *newPerson;
```

You never initialized the XYZPerson object, and that is why it is returning null.